# Parsing HTML with DOM

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, simplexml, domdocument

I am trying to parse HTML for example

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
     <a href='example.com'>Hello, <span>World</span></a>
     <ul>
         <li>
             One item
         </li>
         <li>
             Second item
         </li>
         <li>
             Third item
         </li>
     </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

When I parse this html code with DOM then the nodeValue of "a" tag is "Hello, World". It join the the "span" tag value to "a" tag value. Similarly in "ul" tag its nodeValue is "One ItemSecond ItemThird Item".

I actually want is that, I get "a" tag value which should be "Hello" not "Hello, World".
I have tired textContent instead of nodeValue by both are same.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Well then don’t access the `a` elements overall content, but the content of its first text node.

Comment: @Cbroe That approach solve my problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var c=document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

var X=c.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Variable `X` will give you the Value '`Hello`'